# Select2: Show native UI on touch

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, modernizr

I want to show the native UI on touch-devices despite using Select2. It should still show the nice, styled placeholder, but when clicking, it must show the native UI.

So I thought I could do this:

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {
    $("#id").select2("destroy");
};
```

But the destroy-method removes the styling completely.